# Argument 3 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::request() must be of the type array, string given

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5

I'm experimenting with SammyK/LaravelFacebookSdk.
Trying to run this line from example:
`$response = Facebook::get('/me?fields=id,name,email', 'user-access-token');`

which in turn runs `/var/www/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookGuzzleHttpClient.php line 61`

```
public function send($url, $method, $body, array $headers, $timeOut)
{
    $options = [
        'headers' => $headers,
        'body' => $body,
        'timeout' => $timeOut,
        'connect_timeout' => 10,
        'verify' => __DIR__ . '/certs/DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.pem',
    ];
    $request = $this->guzzleClient->createRequest($method, $url, $options);

    try {
        $rawResponse = $this->guzzleClient->send($request);
    } catch (RequestException $e) {
        $rawResponse = $e->getResponse();

        if ($e->getPrevious() instanceof RingException || !$rawResponse instanceof ResponseInterface) {
            throw new FacebookSDKException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
        }
    }

    $rawHeaders = $this->getHeadersAsString($rawResponse);
    $rawBody = $rawResponse->getBody();
    $httpStatusCode = $rawResponse->getStatusCode();

    return new GraphRawResponse($rawHeaders, $rawBody, $httpStatusCode);
}
```

That calls `/var/www/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php line 87`

```
public function __call($method, $args)
{
    if (count($args) < 1) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Magic request methods require a URI and optional options array');
    }

    $uri = $args[0];
    $opts = isset($args[1]) ? $args[1] : [];

    return substr($method, -5) === 'Async'
        ? $this->requestAsync(substr($method, 0, -5), $uri, $opts)
        : $this->request($method, $uri, $opts);
}
```

This methond interprets input as `array('method' => 'createRequest', 'uri' => 'GET'))`

Changing index seems to correct the error (though other problems araise)

```
 $uri = $args[1];
 $opts = isset($args[2]) ? $args[2] : [];
```

But since it's a very bad practice to edit other packages, how should I correct this error?

Comment: Hi Edmund, not sure have you found the solution for this already? Me here ran into the same issue :(

Comment: @KeithYeoh I dumped the plugin and either wrote code myself or used Socialte (laravels official plugin) + some custome code. I don't really remember. I just remember the feeling that my solution felt much cleaner and simpler than the plugin

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've get the same problem.
Changing indexes won't work for me, but I've found a workaround. Installing php-curl extension switches a whole workflow thru cURL, so the problem is vanished.

Comment: Duh!  Thanks for saving me time.

Comment: OMG. You realy save my time. After 5 days looking for that answer i found here. Tks man.

Comment: Hi guys, sorry new in xampp or php, how do i come about doing the above stated solution?

Comment: From my php.ini I found my php_curl.dll was installed and enabled. Thought I'm still having the same issue?

Comment: @Artur can you tell me what did you do to remove the Argument 3 error?

Comment: @Vivian do you use linux? I do apt install php-curl for ubuntu and that's work

Comment: I'm using window based installed xampp. I checked my php.ini file has php_curl.dll and enabled but still the error persist?

Comment: Cool. Helped me :) installed the extension and the problem was fixed.

Comment: This haunted me in 2019, after an ubuntu update somehow removed curl from my php7.0 installation. Switching to 7.3 where curl was normally installed did the trick. So if you encounter this in 2019 after a system update, check your phpinfo() to make sure you have the extensions and the version you think you have.

Answer (score 4):

Due to Facebook SDK 5.x use guzzle version 5.
So downgrade the guzzle library will workaround

```
$ composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:~5.0
```

Comment: This one solved the problem for me (PHP7.2 + CakePHP4 + graph-sdk5.7)