# use Guzzle 6 to request Ruckus public API, but get Argument 3 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::request() must be of the type array, boolean given

Tags: laravel, api, guzzle

I am using **Guzzle 6** to retrieve data from Ruckus public API, but keeps getting the following error

> Argument 3 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::request() must be of the type
>   array, boolean given

I have googled and searched for similar questions. The only working around is the second answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161355/argument-3-passed-to-guzzlehttp-clientrequest-must-be-of-the-type-array-str) which is to downgrade guzzle version to 5. However, other team members doing other features are using Guzzle 6, so downgrading to version 5 could also be an issue for the team.

Since I am not using any packages like in that post, I don't think the Guzzle version could be the culprit here, so can anyone give me some idea what I have done wrong? Thanks.

By the way, I am using Laravel Command. The code in the handle function is as below:

```
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle()
{
    $client = new Client();
    //to bypass local ssl certificate issuer
    $client->setDefaultOption('verify', false);
    $res = $client->request(
        'POST',
        $this->baseUrl . '/v4_0/session',
        [
            "headers" => [
                "Content-Type" => "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
            ],
            "json" => [
                "username" => "admin",
                "password" => "admin"
            ]
        ]
    );

    $headers = explode(';', $res->getHeader('Set-Cookie'));
    return current($headers);
}
```

The Ruckus public API: http://docs.ruckuswireless.com/vscg-enterprise/vsz-e-public-api-reference-guide-3-5.html#header-overview. I am using version 4, but even I use version 5 I still get the same error.

Comment: can you attempt to use the `$client->post()` instead and see if it shows a different result?

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi yes I tried that as well. Still get the same error.

Comment: do you have php-curl installed ?

Comment: @AnarBayramov Yes I checked. It's installed

Comment: 1. can you try a simply request to something like making a get request that does not require a header. 2. At least check if the guzzle version you have is ` "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",` in your composer.json, reason is that I use this and I don't have problem with it.

Comment: Seems that your code is OK (the third parameter). Could you add more detailed stack trace to the question?

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi @AlexeyShockov  It turns out that `$client->setDefaultOption('verify', false);` is no longer supported.

Comment: eeyah! so have you been able to fix the issue?

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi yes it's been fixed now. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end I logged an issue on the github account of [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1878). It turns out that `$client->setDefaultOption('verify', false);` is no longer a supported function call. Instead it should be passed to the third params like below:

```
$res = $client->request(
    'POST',
    $this->baseUrl . '/v4_0/session',
    [
        "verify" => false,
        "headers" => [
            "Content-Type" => "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
        ],
        "json" => [
            "username" => "admin",
            "password" => "admin"
        ]
    ]
);
```

Thank you for everyone who have given suggestions and tried to help.